# How turn this basic list into a more structured one?

Tags: python, list, loops

I have a fairly basic list as the following :

```
listOne = [parentOneObject,childOne,childTwo,childThree,parentTwoObject,childOne,childTwo...]
```

Sementically, this list contains parents and their child next to them, each iteml is this list is an object (An HTML Element, in reality, but this is not a problem)

Turned into a hierarchy, we get this :

```
-ParentOne
  -Child1
  -Child2
  -Child3
-ParentTwo
  -Child1
  -Child2
```

And so on ...

To distinguish parents,  I check their class attribute if it contains : `level-1` . Other childs have `"level-i"` in their class attribute, where `i` is an integer bigger then one .

I can't find a way to turn that list into a more structured list of dict like this:

```
listTwo = [{
            'parent' : parentOne,
            'children': [childOne,childTwo,childThree]
            },
            {'parent':parentTwo,
             'children': [childOne,childTwo,childThree]
            }]
```

I want to turn the first basic list into a list of dictionaries of parnet and children objects using the logic explained previously .

I know that I should have a t least a minimum code, but for this problem I'm totally stuck, the only code I have for this is :

```
for item in listOne:
   #Do something to turn list one into a structured list
   pass
```

As you can see nothing useful, I'd love to get some help on this, doesn't have to be python, because I'm stuck at the logic level, even pseudocode is fine .

Comment: how to determine parent?

Comment: So how do you distinguish a parent from a child?

Comment: in the class attribute they have this "level-1" , this mean a parent, childs have "level-i" where i is an integer  (not 1). I should have added this to the OP

Answer (score 2):

You need to have a way to distinguish parents from children. Then all you have to do is test for that in a loop:

```
listTwo = []
entry = None
for element in listOne:
    if isparent(element):  # put your test here
        entry = {'parent': element, 'children': []}
        listTwo.append(entry)
    else:  # it's a child, append to last parent
        entry['children'].append(element)
```

So if you can distinguish your HTML elements by a HTML class, then just test for that:

```
if 'level-1' in element.get('class', []):  # it's a parent
```

Note that if the *first* element in `listOne` is not a parent element, the `entry['children']` expression will fail as `entry` is still set to `None` at that stage. This is deliberate, you'd want to know if you had an error like that.